# What does a matrix indexed with two pairs of indices mean?

Tags: matrices, tensors

I came across the following in a paper:

"... we form the matrix $\mathbb{B}$ with entries

$$
B((\hat{j}, \hat{l}), (j, l)) = \sum_{l_1}^{R_A} \sum_{l_2}^{R_A} \left( \sum_{j'}^M A_k^{l_1} (j', \hat{j}) A_k^{l_2} (j', j) \right) \prod_{i\neq k} \langle A_i^{l_1} F_i^l, A_i^{l_2} F_i^{\hat{l}} \rangle
$$"

I haven't come across matrix indexing with two pairs of indices before though. Is $\mathbb{B}$ a block diagonal matrix where $(\hat{j}, \hat{l})$ is the index of the block, and $(j, l)$ is the index within a block?

The paper also forms a vector indexed as $b((\hat{j}, \hat{l}))$, which doesn't make much sense to me either.

Answer (score 0):

This an educated guess. Note that using numbers to name rows and columns in a matrix is an arbitrary choice. And that you don't really use that they are numbers, unless you are using them for something like calculating entries in terms of the corresponding row and column.

So nothing prevents you from using other objects as indices. A common choice is group elements when doing crossed products in certain contexts. Here they seem to be using ordered pairs as their index set. So the rows and columns are indexed each by an ordered pair.

The above is coherent with the notation for the vector; where you would write $b(j)$, now instead of $j$ you use an ordered pair $(\hat j,\hat l)$.